# What is the difference between 现在，此刻 and 此时?

Tags: vocabulary

Until recently I only knew the word 现在 for "now" or "at the moment", but I discoved words "此刻" and "此时" which are also translated as "now" or "this moment". So what is the difference? I read some posts from people and some said it's the same, but some said it is not, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

- 现在 = Now; at present
- 此刻 = At this moment
- 此时 = At this time

现在 is more colloquial (modern)

此刻 and 此时 are more literary (classical)

Examples:

- **现在**美国最高法院共有九位大法官 - **Now** there are nine justices on the U.S. Supreme Court
- 法律上南北韩**此刻**仍在交战状态 - Legally North and South Korea are still at war **at this moment**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

现在 (now, present)

此时 = 这个时候 (this time) - 星期五**此时此地**再見 (See you again on Friday, at **this place this time**.)

此刻 = 现在这个时候/瞬间 (this moment) - **此时此刻**, 吾意已決 (**At this very moment**, my mind has already set/I've made my mind.)

Comment: ”此时此刻, 吾意已決。“ 现代还有人说“吾意”吗？

Comment: @Pedroski If you mean "吾意已決", it is rare but occasionally used in joking and by those junior high schoolers imitating what learned from the literature and TV dramas.

Answer (score 1):

此刻 此时 is less commonly used in everyday conversations. I even can't recall when the last time I used them except writing emails.

此刻 此时 referring to the moment, is less about time and can be used together or interchangeably.
此时/此刻, I'm feeling happy.

现在 referring to the time, similar phrases, such as 立刻, 马上， all about time
现在就去做！ Do it now/at once/asap.

I am speaking in my understanding, do take a grain of salt

Comment: Thanks, I think understand it better now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a concept of relative time when using 现在, because it is compared with 过去 和 将来. While 此时 and 此刻 (此时此刻）are absolute concepts, just at this moment. For example,

现在东西真贵呀！It’s so expensive now. (Compared with last year).

你现在不买房子，以后就更买不起了。 If you don’t buy a house now, you might can’t afford it in the future.